# Angularjs $location.search with duplicate parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a URL like this:

`myappl/services=1&services=5&services=4` etc...

I need to create an array with the services values

I try with

```
$scope.checkservices =  [$location.search().services].map(Number); }
```

But it work only if there is only 1 *services* param.

How can I loop my services param?

Comment: `Object.keys($location.search()).map(( c, i, o) => o[c])` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angularJS, you can use `$location` module to get the params values. Below is a code snippet.

```
angular.module('app-name').controller('controller', ['$location',function($location){
    var key_value = $location.search();
    console.log(Object.values(key_value))
}])
```

The code above will give you the param values in objects like according to your url the `key_value` here will be

```
key_value = {
  services1: "1",
  services2: "5",
  services3: "4"
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it give you just `key_value = { services: 4 } `?

Comment: @AdityaParab No It won't.

Comment: Thank you. Easier than I thought

Comment: @frwebdev I hope `services=1&services=5&services=4` it's not only services there are different params name as well. Am i correct ?

Comment: @Lokesh yes, i have also other param, but when i have the object  I can handle it easily

Comment: @frwebdev yea you can also do that, In case if you want it in array check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the accepted answer is the best or correct answer. Just include [**`$routeParams`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) in your controller, directive or whatever :

```
var params = $routeParams.services;
```

params will be `["1", "5", "4"]`, i.e an array with the services values ...

If you have the example path above `myappl/services=1&services=5&services=4`